# how to construct a fancy bar chart

Tags: charts, code-review, code-request

I have the following code to produce an `almost` fancy `BarChart`:

```
countries = CountryData["G7"];
data = {{2, 1, 1.5, 3, 3, 2.5, 4}, {-2, -1, -1.5, -3, -3, -2.5, -2}};
BarChart[data, PlotLabel -> "GDP Per Capita", PlotTheme -> "Business",
  ChartLabels -> Placed[countries, Below, Rotate[#, Pi/2.4] &], 
 ChartStyle -> {{Blue, Green}, None}, 
 ChartLegends -> {{"high", "low"}, None}]
```

[image]

My goal is to generate the following format:

[image]

I want to have the following modifications to convert my `BarChart` above. (1) Add a box `Downside Scenario` to the top of the bar chart in Brown color, and inside the same box add a line of text in small fonts like `This is a scenario parameter set`, (2) Add a secondary plot label `GDP Per Capita` in bold, and (3) add a second line of text under GDP per capita such as `parameter domain: {1,2,3}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First thoughts...

```
countries = CountryData["G7"];
data = {{2, 1, 1.5, 3, 3, 2.5, 4}, {-2, -1, -1.5, -3, -3, -2.5, -2}};

Column[{
  TextCell["GDP Per Capital", "Section", FontColor -> White],
  TextCell["This is a scenario parameter set", FontSize -> 12, 
   FontColor -> White],
  "",
  TextCell["WorldGDP in 2020", FontWeight -> Bold, FontSize -> 20],
  TextCell["parameter domain:{1,2,3}", FontWeight -> Bold, 
   FontSize -> 12],
  "",
  TextCell["% Difference from baseline and contributions in % pts", 
   "TI"],
  BarChart[data,
   PlotTheme -> "Business",
   ChartLabels -> Placed[countries, Below, Rotate[#, Pi/2.4] &],
   ChartStyle -> {{Blue, Green}, None},
   ChartLegends -> {{"high", "low"}, None},
   ImageSize -> 500]
  },
 Alignment -> Center,
 Background -> {Automatic, {1 -> Darker[Red], 2 -> Darker[Red]}}]
```

[image]

Vary your text and colors as desired.

Comment: It is a nice figure. thanks very much.